# jquery addClass to div selected by attribute

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an accordion on one page. From another page I want to link to the accordion page and open a specific accordion item directly by adding 'active' to the class of the div of that item. Using window.location.hash to select the correct div.

HTML accordion page:

```
<div id="accordion_sp1_id118" class="sp-accordion sp-accordion-style3 ">
 <div class="sp-accordion-item">
  <div id="#78" class="toggler">
   <span>My accordion header 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sp-accordion-container" style="display: none;">
   <div class="sp-accordion-inner">
    <p>Content panel accordion 1</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="sp-accordion-item">
 <div id="#99" class="toggler">
  <span>My accordion header 2</span>
 </div>
 <div class="sp-accordion-container" style="display: none;">
  <div class="sp-accordion-inner">
   <p>Content panel accordion 2</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="sp-accordion-item">
 <div id="#92" class="toggler">
  <span>My accordion header 3</span>
 </div>
 <div class="sp-accordion-container" style="display: none;">
  <div class="sp-accordion-inner">
   <p>Content panel accordion 3</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // YOU CAN NOW USE $ AS YOUR jQUERY OBJECT.
  $('div[id="'+location.hash+'"]').addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

The url to the accordion page contains for example '#92' to link to div with id '#92'. This div should get 'active' added to its class.
Script does'nt seem to work however: where is the mistake??

Please help, been stuck on this too long. I know much too little about jquery!

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that the hash value could contain a leading `#`(I don't think it is uniform across older browsers so we need to handle both cases)

```
$('div[id="'+location.hash.replace(/^#/, '')+'"]').addClass('active');
```

or using id selector

```
$(location.hash.replace(/^([^#])/, '#$1')).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the document to activate the accordion use the following

// Getter => 
    var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );

// Setter
     => $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

hope this will be helpfull.